# Merge github zip downloads with repo sync

Tags: github, repository

I was trying to download cm9 sources, but it seems like it will take forever, with endless resyncs.

Github offers repos as zip files, which can be downloaded and resumed with any download accelerator. Is there any way to extract those zips into my repo's folder and make the repo command think that they have been synced?

The reason i cannot continue with repo command's method is that, my connection keeps dropping everytime theres a gust of wind, and repo command just freezes after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. download the zip/tarball propose by GitHub
2. `git clone --bare` the GitHub repo (so no checkout: it *may* be easier with your shaky connection)
3. move the `xxx.git` directory (renaming it '`.git`') created by the clone into the uncompressed repo content from step 1.
4. remove the bare attribute in the `.git` moved directory: `git config --bool core.bare false`

If a `clone --bare` doesn't work, then this approach would not be useful.
And a restartable clone (which was [considered in 2009](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Continue-git-clone-after-interruption-td3458217.html), even [formalized as a SoC](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SoC2009Ideas#Restartable_Clone)) isn't yet a reality.